# I need to get information about a VM using curl

Tags: api, rest

I need to get information about a VM using curl with REST calls. I have this information where 1701 is the VM ID

```
GET /api/v1/vms/1701 HTTP/1.1
Host: vmlam.ral.sf.com
Authorization: Token token=4210
```

I tried this in cygwin but it did not work

```
c:/curl-7.69.0-win64-mingw/bin/curl -X GET -d '{Authorization: Token token=4210}' 'https:/vmlam.ral.sf.com//api/v1/vms/1701'

 curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
 certificate More details here: curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html curl
 failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
 establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this
 situation and how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned
 above.
```

Comment: Please be more specific, whats the context? What have you tried? What technologies are being used? etc.

Comment: I tried this in cygwin but it did not work 

c:/curl-7.69.0-win64-mingw/bin/curl -X GET -d '{Authorization: Token token=4210}' 'https:/vmlam.ral.sf.com//api/v1/vms/1701'

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

Comment: Try adding the options -k, --insecure these allow you to bypass the cert check.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a certificate issue, you can skip the check with the option -k (or --insecure)

From curl documentation (man curl):

```
-k, --insecure
      (TLS) By default, every SSL connection curl makes is verified to be secure. This option allows curl to proceed and operate even for server connections other‐
      wise considered insecure.

      The server connection is verified by making sure the server's certificate contains the right name and verifies successfully using the cert store.

      See this online resource for further details:
      https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

      See also --proxy-insecure and --cacert.
```

Comment: I added the -K option but still has the same error. Is the format of the CURL command correct?